# RBAC access in Azure Web App

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-active-directory

I am trying to use RBAC for authorization in Azure Web App. I am following the example as described [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-roleclaims/). But this article points to Old azure portal. How can I create and assign roles (like 'Full-Time Employee', 'Vendor' etc..) in Azure AD in new Azure Portal?

Comment: do you want to provide restriction on a single web app or resources inside your subscription ?

Comment: I am not looking to provide RBAC access on Azure resource. In Azure Web App manifest, we update _'appRoles'_ setting with all Application Roles. I want to know where to create and assign these roles in Azure AD through Azure Resource Management Portal? If not, how to do it programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In new portal , you could assign application role in `Enterprise applications` blade after updating 'appRoles' setting with application roles in manifest .

You could refer to [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-coreapps-assign-user-azure-portal) for detail steps . In `select Role` blade , you will find the roles you defined in manifest:

[image]